# Which of the following are valid URI's(Uniform Resource Identifier) as per the REST API specifications?

Tags: api, rest, uri

How to identify which of the following Uniform Resource Identifier(URI) is valid as per REST API specifications.

*Choose one or more options*

```
1. POST https://api.example.com/whales/create/9xf3df

2. PUT https://api.example.com/whales/9xf3df

3. GET https://api.example.com/whales/9xf3df?sort=name&valid=true

4. DELETE https://api.example.com/whales
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers; anything that conforms to the production rules defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) is *fine*.

```
/whales/create/9xf3df
/whales/9xf3df
/whales/9xf3df?sort=name&valid=true
/whales 

/0cc846bb-678d-45d8-9c06-d9cf94cee0a5
/9xf3df/whales
```

These are all *fine* identifiers.

Identifiers for a "REST API" are exactly like identifiers for web pages - you can use any spelling you want, and the browsers, caches, web crawlers, and so on will work with them quite happily; these general purpose components treat identifiers like identifiers - they don't try to extract any meaning from them.

By way of demonstration, please observe that all of the following work exactly the way you would expect them to:

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/create
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delete

> Does REST care about the POST, PUT, GET, and DELETE for the above options?

Hard to be sure which question you are asking here.

```
PUT /dictionary/delete HTTP/1.1
```

That's a perfectly satisfactory request-line, and there is no ambiguity about what it means.  In this example, PUT is the [method-token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1); that tells the server that we are requesting that the representation of the target resource (identified by `/dictionary/delete`) be replaced by the representation include in the message-body of the request

For this specific resource, that probably means that the message-body is an HTML document (we'd see `Content-Type: text/html` in the headers, to ensure that the server knows how to correctly interpret the bytes provided).

```
PATCH /dictionary/delete HTTP/1.1
```

This is also a satisfactory request line; we are again requesting a change to the representation of the `/dictionary/delete` resource, but we're going about it in a slightly different way - instead of including a replacement representation in the message body, we're providing a representation of a list of changes to make (aka a "patch document").

Uniform interface means that we should expect the folks at `www.merriam-webster.com` to understand these messages exactly as we've described them here.

Now, for these specific resources, they probably don't want random stack-overflow members making changes to their website, so they are likely to respond [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) or [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5).

All of the general purpose components will understand what that means, again because the standardized response meta-data is common to all resources.

Comment: Does REST care about the POST, PUT, GET, and DELETE for the above options?